# Angular, where is the input function fn:any come from in ControlValueAccessor interface, registerOnTouched(fn: any)

Tags: angular

custom-input-test.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-input-test',
  templateUrl: './custom-input-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-input-test.component.css']
})
export class CustomInputTestComponent implements OnInit {
  external : string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

custom-input-test.component.html

```
<p>
    input:
    </p>
    
      <app-custom-input [(ngModel)]="external" name="externalVal" ></app-custom-input>
      external: {{external}}
```

custom-input.component.ts

```
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-input',
  template: `<input [(ngModel)]="test"/>Test:{{test}}
  <br/> 
  <input [(ngModel)]="value"/>local: {{val}}
  <br/>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  constructor() { }

  onChange: any = () => {}
  onTouch: any = () => {}
  val= ""
  //value = "";
  
  set value(val){
    console.log("setter");
    if( val !== undefined && this.val !== val){
    this.val = val
    this.onChange(val)
    this.onTouch(val)
    }
   
  }
  

  writeValue(value: any){
    this.value = value
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any){
    this.onChange = fn
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any){
    this.onTouch = fn
  }

}
```

The question is
for
`registerOnChange(fn: any){...`

I google and this function is for

> The registerOnChange accepts a callback function which you can call
> when changes happen so that you can notify the outside world that the
> data model has changed.

but I check on breakpoint, the fn is

```
        control._pendingValue = newValue;
        control._pendingChange = true;
        control._pendingDirty = true;
        if (control.updateOn === 'change')
            updateCon…
```

where is the function come from and why this function becomes input parameter of registerOnChange(fn: any)?

[image]